# Magmi question assign products to different root category

Tags: magento-1.9, magmi

I am uploading products through magmi, works fine but somehow he always adds my produts to my default root category, but he should add it to my second root category.

I just have the column categories with below value

rootcat2/category1/category2;;rootcat2/category2/category3

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a wild guess and say that you meant to use the "On-the-Fly Category Importer" plugin of Magmi, but you didn't actually check the box to use it.

Magmi, without the category importer plugin, normally takes category IDs (at least for an older version I used a while back). If you want to use `rootcat2/category1/category2;;rootcat2/category2/category3`, you must use the On-the-Fly Category Importer.

Check out the wiki: http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=On_the_fly_category_creator/importer

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have the checkbox ticked :-) He also creates all the category's but under the default root category.